# WPF ControlTemplate and Binding

Tags: wpf

In the below code, `MousePressImage` is a dependency property of class `ButtonControl`. 
The following Binding doesn't work. Appreciate your help in solving this issue.

```
Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                Path=MousePressImage}"/>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonControl}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonControl}">
        <Border>
          <Image x:Name="img"
                 Source="pack://application:,,,/Recipe_06_13;component/Resources/normal.bmp"
                 />
        </Border>
        <!--<Border x:Name="border">
          <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="img"
                        ImageSource="/Recipe_06_13;component/Resources/fatal.png"/>
          </Border.Background>
        </Border>-->
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="img" 
                    Property="Source" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                                Path=MousePressImage}"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I create the `ButtonControl` like this.

```
<local:ButtonControl Height="48" Width="160" 
  MouseOverImage="pack://application:,,,/Recipe_06_13;component/Resources/Over.bmp"
  MousePressImage="pack://application:,,,/Recipe_06_13;component/Resources/Press.bmp"
  DisableImage=" ">
</local:ButtonControl>
```

Comment: What object has the property 'Value'?  Note that this Value property will need to be a dependency property in order for the Binding to work.  MousePressImage actually doesn't have to be a dependency property, though that simplifies the property changed notification.

Comment: Dan,Thanks for your reply.. The value is for the property 'Source', I think Source is a dependency property...see below. However, the binding still doesn't work... Am I missing something?

        <Border> 
          <Image x:Name="img" 
                 Source="pack://application:,,,/Recipe_06_13;component/Resources/normal.bmp" 
                 /> 
        </Border>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your trigger is on a ControlTemplate, you need to be getting the MousePressImage from the *control instance being templated*.  To do this, use `TemplateBinding` or (more reliably) `RelativeSource TemplatedParent`:

```
<Setter TargetName="img" 
        Property="Source" 
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                        Path=MousePressImage}" />
```

Comment: IsMouseOver shouldn't result in flicker, because it shouldn't change except when the mouse-over status changes.  You might want to work up a simple repro for this and post it as a separate question -- that will probably get more attention and better answers than a discussion in comments!  Also, I think you may have mistaken me for someone else -- I've never worked at Solyndra -- sorry!