# WPF - Tooltip Databinding not working when setting IsOpen=true

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a button which has a ToolTip attached to it.

There are data-bound information inside the ToolTip.

I am displaying the ToolTip on click as well as on MouseOver.

By using the code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        tt = btn.ToolTip as ToolTip;
        tt.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

If I click the button, the ToolTip is displayed, but without the data-values.

[image]

But if I hover the mouse over the button, it displays correctly.

[image]

**Important**

If I hover over it first, get the tooltip, take the mouse away and then come again and click, it displays correctly.

So I'm guessing that I need to do some kind of call for the tooltip to get the databound info when I call the `tt.IsOpen = true`

How can I achieve the complete display of tooltip by manually calling it?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

The xaml code.

```
<Button Content="{x:Static prop:strings.Info}" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click" >
                                <Button.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip>
                                        <ToolTip.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                                                <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" CornerRadius="5">
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                        <DockPanel>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static prop:strings.Laenge}" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LaengeD}"  Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                                                        </DockPanel>
                                                        <DockPanel >
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static prop:strings.Breite}" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding BreiteD}"  Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                                                        </DockPanel>
                                                        <DockPanel>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static prop:strings.Hoehe}" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HoeheD}"  Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                                                        </DockPanel>
                                                        <DockPanel>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static prop:strings.Gewicht}" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Gewicht}"  Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                                                        </DockPanel>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Border>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </ToolTip.Template>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </Button.ToolTip>
                            </Button>
```

Comment: Shall we just guess what your problem is, or will you give us a clue by showing us *all* the relevant code?

Comment: *There are data-bound information inside the ToolTip*, where? Post xaml please.

Comment: @Sinatr Added the xaml code

Comment: `ControlTemplate` is typically using `TemplateBinding`. I am not quite sure if normal binding will work (you may need to use some trick, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2530837/1997232)). Do you really need template here? Try to simply put `Border` and children inside tooltip content.

Comment: Does clicking the button _always_ show a tooltip with blank values? Or is it only before you hover over it? If you click on it after you have hovered, is it still the same problem?

Comment: @Sinatr I removed both `<ToolTip.Template>` and `<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">` . But still the same thing is happening.

Comment: @MikeEason It is only before hovering over it. When I click on it after hovering, it works as expected.

Comment: @AarVee Looks like you are setting the object in your Hover event, but not your click event. Make sure that both update/create the object that you are binding to.

Comment: @MikeEason The hover event is inherently done without any code for Tooltips. I'm looking for what extra I need to do in the click event. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your `Tooltip` is hidden, its `PlacementTarget` property is set to null and it is not linked to the logic tree of your button.
In this case your `{Binding LaengeD}` can't retrieve the correct value.
On the other side if you hover the button the `PlacementTarget` property is correctly set and your Binding can work.

So you can use this solution: add a DataContext binding to your tooltip

```
<Button Content="Click me" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click" >
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
            <ToolTip.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" CornerRadius="5">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="Laenge" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LaengeD}" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                            </DockPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToolTip.Template>
        </ToolTip>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Then change your click event handler in this way:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    ToolTip tt = btn.ToolTip as ToolTip;

    if (tt.PlacementTarget == null)
    {
        tt.PlacementTarget = btn;
    }

    tt.IsOpen = true;
}
```